# Ajuda com Z-index em 3 elementos

Tags: css, angular, z-index

Estou com um problema relacionado a qual div aparecerá por cima da outra. Quando eu passar o mouse em cima de algum icone, quero que o icone fique azul e apareça uma mensagem (grudada ao icone) mostrando o que é aquela imagem. Tentei usar o z-index para tentar resolver isso, mas não está funcionando. A mensagem só não cobre a imagem caso eu use z-index com valor negativo, só que dessa forma, a mensagem também ficará coberta por outros elementos... como posso resolver isso? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.menu-vertical {
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    float: left;
    height: calc(100vh - 2px);
    margin-left: -40px;
    width: 50px;

    .item1 {
        background-image: url('/assets/img/menu.png');
        background-position: 50% 80%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-top: 40px; 

    }
    
    .item2{
        background-image: url('/assets/img/oportunidades.png');
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 60px;
        margin-top: 20px; 
        

        &:hover {
            background-image: url('/assets/img/propostas_hover.png');
           
        }

    
        & .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            background-color: #20A2FA;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 8.9px;
            border-top-left-radius: 8px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            margin-left: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 73px;
            width: 150px;
            
            
          }
          
        &:hover .tooltiptext {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            visibility: visible;
    
        }

    }

  

    .item3{
        background-image: url('/assets/img/propostas.png');
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 60px;
        margin-top: 40px; 
       
        

        &:hover {
            background-image: url('/assets/img/propostas_hover.png');
            
        }

        & .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            background-color: #20A2FA;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 8.9px;
            border-top-left-radius: 8px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            margin-left: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 173px;
            width: 150px;
            
          }
          
        &:hover .tooltiptext {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            visibility: visible;
            
        }

    }

     .item4{
        background-image: url('/assets/img/cadastros.png');
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 60px;
        margin-top: 40px; 

        &:hover {
            background-image: url('/assets/img/cadastros_hover.png');
            
        }

        & .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            background-color: #20A2FA;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 8.9px;
            border-top-left-radius: 8px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            margin-left: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 273px;
            width: 150px;
            
          }
          
        &:hover .tooltiptext {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            visibility: visible;
            
        }


    }
    
    .item5 {
        background-image: url('../../../assets/img/voltar.png');
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 60px;
        margin-top: 40px; 

        &:hover {
            background-image: url('/assets/img/voltar_hover.png');
            
        }

        & .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            background-color: #20A2FA;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 8.9px;
            border-top-left-radius: 8px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            margin-left: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 373px;
            width: 150px;
            
          }
          
        &:hover .tooltiptext {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            visibility: visible;
            
        }


    }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-vertical">
  <div class="item1">
  </div>
  <div class="item2"><span class="tooltiptext">Oportunidades</span></div>
  <div class="item3"><span class="tooltiptext">Propostas</span></div>
  <div class="item4"><span class="tooltiptext">Cadastros</span></div>
  <div class="item5"><span class="tooltiptext">Voltar</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara só com essa parte do código não da para te ajudar pq não da para simular o seu problema...

Answer (score 0):

Como dito no comentário, não da pra reproduzir o erro 100%;
Mas, pela imagem, deve ser os z-index do .menu-vertical e da div em que está o elemento do " + nova oportunidade". como o .menu-vertical não tem z-index declarado, seus filhos podem ficar abaixo de algum elemento.

acho que isso se resolveria com a declaração de um z-index: 100; no .menu-vertical.